# Deserializing JSON array into strongly typed .NET object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net, hammock

When I can call the 3rd party api and get back a single class worth of data everything deserialises fine using this code

```
TheUser me = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(response, typeof(TheUser)) as TheUser
```

The problem comes when I try and deserialise JSON response content that is an array, such as

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "A Jones",
         "id": "500015763"
      },
      {
         "name": "B Smith",
         "id": "504986213"
      },
      {
         "name": "C Brown",
         "id": "509034361"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can only get the serialization to work if I use a custom wrapping class around the "data" member and that member needs to be of type `List<object>`. If it have them as type `List<TheUser>` I get `ArgumentException` from the `JsonParser DesializeType` method.

I originally tried to serialise without a wrapping type like this

```
List<TheUser> freinds = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(response, typeof(List<TheUser>)) as List<TheUser>;
```

but that just returns me an empty collection. Surely I must be able to have the array deserialize to a strongly typed list.

Comment: I have the same problem; if you deserialize `response` into a `dynamic` var instead of `TheUser`, then `deserialized.data` is available as a `JArray` -- any idea if you can convert that into `List<something>`?

Comment: Seems you should be able to ([link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Afer looking at [the source](http://hammock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fed040573260#src/net40/Hammock.WindowsPhone/Hammock.WindowsPhone.csproj), for WP7 Hammock doesn't actually use Json.Net for JSON parsing. Instead it uses it's own parser which doesn't cope with custom types very well.

If using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) directly it is possible to deserialize to a strongly typed collection inside a wrapper object.

```
var response = @"
    {
        ""data"": [
            {
                ""name"": ""A Jones"",
                ""id"": ""500015763""
            },
            {
                ""name"": ""B Smith"",
                ""id"": ""504986213""
            },
            {
                ""name"": ""C Brown"",
                ""id"": ""509034361""
            }
        ]
    }
";

var des = (MyClass)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeof(MyClass));

return des.data.Count.ToString();
```

and with:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<User> data { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Having to create the extra object with the data property is annoying but that's a consequence of the way the JSON formatted object is constructed.

Documentation: **[Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)**

Comment: It is very easy to change DeSerializer in Hammock. Create a class that implements the Hammock.Serialization.IDeserializer interface. And then set that class as your Deserializer on the RestClient.

Comment: I agree that it's slightly annoying to add the extra object, hence my solution below.  My approach also gets around you having to case like you are in the var des = (MyClass)... line.  Not sure if either this or my solution is better than the other, just prefer not having to add the extra Data object and I generally try to avoid type casting.

Comment: How much does it make to first do a `Json.Parse(jsonString)` and then do a `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(parsedJson["data"]).ToString())` to finally obtain a list of `User`, performance and sanity wise? ;-)

Comment: I read this thread multiple times debugging the same problem.  In my case I had to get the JSON in the right format for processing by the JSON.Net package.  What I would offer to others facing a similar problem is use a TraceWriter as the error message help highlight a fault I did not see in the JSON file.

Answer (score 21):

try

```
List<TheUser> friends = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TheUser>>(response);
```

Comment: That doesn't compile, however isn't that just a differnt calling style that is going to result in the same underlying mthods being called in the same way? I do not see how that will get around my issue

Comment: This worked for me: `List<TheUser> friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TheUser>>(response);`

Comment: Thanks! This allowed me to deserialize an array of objects without wrapping them in a container object.

Comment: I like Homer's solution, I agree it's a bit cleaner than my solution as it obviates the need for having a parent class or having to implement an interface if you don't want to inherit from anything.  -Eric

Comment: this one works for me with similar problem.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me for deserializing JSON into an array of objects:

```
List<TheUser> friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TheUser>>(response);
```

Answer (score 9):

This solution seems to work for me and gets around having to code a bunch of classes with "Data" in them.

```
public interface IDataResponse<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataResponse<T> : IDataResponse<T> where T : class
{
   [JsonProperty("data")]
   public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I should have included this to begin with, here is an example method using the above:

```
public List<TheUser> GetUser()
{
    var results = GetUserJson();
    var userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataResponse<TheUser>>(results.ToString());

    return userList.Data.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Json.NET - Documentation

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SelectToken.htm

Interpretation for the author

```
var o = JObject.Parse(response);
var a = o.SelectToken("data").Select(jt => jt.ToObject<TheUser>()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSON structure looks very familiar to a problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079825/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-property-where-the-property-name-is-dependent-on-t) - The answer there was to treat the JSON representation as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, even though there was only 1 entry.

If I am correct your key is of type string and the value of a `List<T>` where `T` represents the class `TheUser`.

If you want better serialisation performance check out using [Silverlight Serializer](http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer/), you'll need to build a WP7 version. Shameless plug - I wrote a blog post about [this](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/03/wp7contrib-why-we-use.html).

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach, it is visual for me.

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
          var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
          JObject result = JObject.Parse(response);
          var users = result.SelectToken("data");   
          List<User> userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(users.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is because the json represents an object with the list of users as a property. Try deserializing to something like:

```
public class UsersResponse
{
    public List<User> Data { get; set; }
}
```