# Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "Acc 1",
                    "Values": [
                        "Acc 1"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "Id",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "1",
                    "Values": [
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Name": "account",
        "Id": "1"
    },
    {
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "Acc 2",
                    "Values": [
                        "Acc 2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "Id",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "2",
                    "Values": [
                        "2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Name": "account",
        "Id": "2"
    },
    {
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "Acc 3",
                    "Values": [
                        "Acc 3"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "Id",
                "Value": {
                    "Value": "3",
                    "Values": [
                        "3"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Name": "account",
        "Id": "2"
    }
]
```

And I have these classes:

```
public class RetrieveMultipleResponse
{
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the above JSON using the code below:

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveMultipleResponse>(JsonStr);
```

but I am getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'test.Model.RetrieveMultipleResponse' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements
>   a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Your JSON string is wrapped within square brackets (`[]`), hence it is interpreted as an array instead of as a single `RetrieveMultipleResponse` object. Therefore, you need to deserialize it to a type of collection of `RetrieveMultipleResponse`, for example:

```
var objResponse1 = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RetrieveMultipleResponse>>(JsonStr);
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep it as a single object instead of a collection, could you just do JsonStr.Replace("[","").Replace("]","")  or would this not be good practice?

Comment: This solution is not working when serialized from DataTable and then deserializing back to DataTable. Getting the same error when deserializing because the JSON is an array.

Answer (score 14):

If one wants to support Generics (in an extension method) this is the pattern...

```
public  static List<T> Deserialize<T>(this string SerializedJSONString)
{
    var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(SerializedJSONString);
    return stuff;
}
```

It is used like this:

```
var rc = new MyHttpClient(URL);
//This response is the JSON Array (see posts above)
var response = rc.SendRequest();
var data = response.Deserialize<MyClassType>();
```

MyClassType looks like this (must match name value pairs of JSON array)

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
 public class MyClassType
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Manager")]
    public string Manager { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastUpdate")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
 }
```

Use NUGET to download Newtonsoft.Json add a reference where needed...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: What are generics and why would one want to support them? How does this answer the question asked? Where does this code come from? This looks like an answer to a totally different question.

Comment: To get more specific, OP already has all of this structure set up (more or less correctly) in their question. Their issue is a type disparity between their JSON and their C# and they need help resolving it. This answer currently doesn't explain which part of it solves OP's problem or how.

Answer (score 5):

Can't add a comment to the solution but that didn't work for me. The solution that worked for me was to use:

> ```
> var des = (MyClass)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeof(MyClass)); 
> return des.data.Count.ToString();
> ```

[Deserializing JSON array into strongly typed .NET object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979434/deserializing-json-array-into-strongly-typed-net-object)

Comment: "*Can't add a comment to the solution*" What solution are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Use this, `FrontData` is JSON string:

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTransfer>>(FrontData);
```

and extract list:

```
var a = objResponse1[0];
var b = a.CustomerData;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first element (Key) try this method and it will be the same for the others:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("Your URL"))
    {
        var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var list = JObject.Parse(apiResponse)["Attributes"].Select(el => new {  Key= (string)el["Key"] }).ToList();
        var Keys= list.Select(p => p.Key).ToList();
    }
}
```