# Error in deserialising the objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string.

```
[  
 {  
  "target":"FDOL00001",
  "datapoints":[  
     {  
        "y":72.564,
        "x":1523858700
     }
  ]
 },
 {  
  "target":"FDOL00001",
  "datapoints":[  
     {  
        "y":86.366,
        "x":1523858700
     }
  ]
 },
 {  
  "target":"FDOL00001",
  "datapoints":[  
     {  
        "y":73.90195818815343,
        "x":1523858700
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

I am trying to deserialise it to a collection. But I am getting an error. Can somebody direct me to the right way to fix this?

```
class datapoint
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public int x { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public decimal y { get; set; }
}
class jsonMapper
{
    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public string target { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("datapoints")]
    public datapoint datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert using the following code.

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonMapper>>(objText);
```

The error I am getting is

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ISSPortal2.datapoint' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '[0].datapoints', line 1, position 40.

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ) . But its not working.
What's wrong in my code. Please help me to identify that. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `public datapoint datapoints { get; set; }` should be something like `List<datapoint> datapoints { get; set; }` ...?

Comment: Top tip: You can copy the JSON string to the clipboard and then use Visual Studio 2017 to paste it into a source code file via `Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as Classes` and it will give you the right class declarations (although you will likely have to fiddle around with the results a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize array `datapoint[]` into `datapoint`.

Change

```
public datapoint datapoints { get; set; }
```

To

```
public datapoint[] datapoints { get; set; }
```

**Bonus:** C# Naming Conventions, suggest you to use Capital Letters in public properties.

```
class Datapoint
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public int X { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
}
class JsonMapper
{
    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public string Target { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("datapoints")]
    public Datapoint Datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Orel Eraki. It worked. Also special thanks for the Bonus points. This is what I used to forget sometimes. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `datapoints` as a collection of some sort (e.g. an `IEnumerable`, or an `IList`)

```
class jsonMapper
{
    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public string target { get; set; }

    // This has changed to IEnumerable<datapoint>
    [JsonProperty("datapoints")]
    public IEnumerable<datapoint> datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should be like this :

```
public class datapoint
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public int x { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public decimal y { get; set; }
}
public class jsonMapper
{
    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public string target { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("datapoints")]
    public List<datapoint> datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your json string on `datapoints` property for each `jsonMapper` object is wrapped within square brackets (`[]`), then `datapoints` is interpreted as collection object instead of single object.
Your jsonMapper class is

```
class jsonMapper
{
    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public string target { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("datapoints")]
    public datapoint datapoints { get; set; }
}
```

and `datapoints` property is not array or any collection object.

you can change your property from `public datapoint datapoints { get; set; };` to 
`public List<datapoint> datapoints { get; set; };` or you can remove square brackets (`[]`) from your json string.