# Deserialize Json into class C#

Tags: c#, json

I am retrieving the JSON body from an API. I want to deserialize the Json into class and get the specific data I want to append into Picker (Xamarin Forms). I keep on getting error and I am not sure how to resolve this issue. This is my first time doing deserialize so I hope someone can help me on this! Thank you

**Error**

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'App123.UserDetails[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Error', line 1, position 9.'`

**JSON**

```
{
"Error": null,
"Success": true,
"Data": {
    "Message": "Success",
    "NextPrompt": null,
    "NextDefaultValue": "",
    "IsFinished": false,
    "ReturnData": [
        {
            "User": "M0001",
            "Role": "Admin",
            "Password": "abc2020",
            "Contact": "98780101",
            "Department": "HR"
        },
        {
            "User": "M1043",
            "Role": "Director",
            "Password": "zxy2020",
            "Contact": "91235678",
            "Department": "Finance"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Class**

```
public class UserDetails
{
public class Rootobject
{
public object Error { get; set; }
public bool Success { get; set; }
public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
public string Message { get; set; }
public object NextPrompt { get; set; }
public string NextDefaultValue { get; set; }
public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
public Returndata[] ReturnData { get; set; }
}

public class Returndata
{
public string User { get; set; }
public string Role { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Contact { get; set; }
public string Department { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Code**

```
(code on API connection)
 var response = await client2.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        string text = responsebody.ToString();
        string[] strText = text.Split(new[] { ',', ':', '}', '{', ']', '[', '\\', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
UserDetails[] userdetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails[]>(text);

        UserPicker.ItemsSource = userdetails;
```

Comment: It's not an array you're deserializing. Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(text);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ) The exact duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it look like json not match class.
maybe try this?

```
   string text = responsebody.ToString();
   Rootobject userdetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(text);
```

Comment: Hey thank you! This works well :) I was able to retrieve the values but I can't get it added into the picker...

Answer (score 0):

According to your Json data, you need to deserialize the `Rootobject`.

Not `UserDetails`. Plus you don't need to be worry about array as long as your serialize string format is correct.

Here is testing about json serialize/deserialize on your class.

```
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
        // Returndata
        Returndata returndata_1 = new Returndata()
        {
            User = "M0001",
            Role = "Admin",
            Password = "abc2020",
            Contact = "98780101",
            Department = "HR"
        };
        Returndata returndata_2 = new Returndata()
        {
            User = "M1043",
            Role = "Director",
            Password = "zxy2020",
            Contact = "91235678",
            Department = "Finance"
        };
        Returndata[] returndatas = { returndata_1, returndata_2 };

        // Data
        Data data = new Data()
        {
            Message = "Success",
            NextPrompt = null,
            NextDefaultValue = "",
            IsFinished = false,
            ReturnData = returndatas
        };

        // Rootobject
        Rootobject rootobject = new Rootobject()
        {
            Error = null,
            Success = true,
            Data = data
        };

        string serializeText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootobject);
        Rootobject deserializeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(serializeText);

        Console.ReadLine();  
  }
```