# c# > Json Deserialize with "recurrent objects"

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I 'm working with visual studio and c# and I'm beginner.... :-(

I want to deserialize this json response :

```
[
{
    "id": 10076,
    "nom": "00 Test Api Upload"
},
{
    "id": 9730,
    "nom": "2021 Vacances Sabran Gruissan",
    "**childs**": [
        {
            "id": 9731,
            "nom": "Gruissan"
        },
        {
            "id": 9745,
            "nom": "Sabran"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I Try to do this :

```
    public class Child
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nom { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nom { get; set; }
        public IList<Child> childs { get; set; }
    }

    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
```

But it's not ok

I have this kind of error :

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'GpxToolZ.VisuGpx+Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects, not just the one, so instead of Root try to use Root[]
or try this code

```
var jD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data[]>(json);
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nom")]
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("childs", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Child[] Childs { get; set; }
}

public partial class Child
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nom")]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!! :o)

Comment: It's Work, with your "rewriting"... Thanks a lot !