# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am new to JSON string handling in C# and have the following error when trying to deserialize a JSON string:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Formula1Info.Models.clsMRData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'MRData.xmlns', line 1, position 19.
```

The JSON string is:

```
{"MRData":{"xmlns":"http:\/\/ergast.com\/mrd\/1.5","series":"f1","url":"http://ergast.com/api/f1/1952.json","limit":"30","offset":"0","total":"8","RaceTable":{"season":"1952","Races":[{"season":"1952","round":"1","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_Swiss_Grand_Prix","raceName":"Swiss Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"bremgarten","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Circuit_Bremgarten","circuitName":"Circuit Bremgarten","Location":{"lat":"46.9589","long":"7.40194","locality":"Bern","country":"Switzerland"}},"date":"1952-05-18"},{"season":"1952","round":"2","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_Indianapolis_500","raceName":"Indianapolis 500","Circuit":{"circuitId":"indianapolis","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Indianapolis_Motor_Speedway","circuitName":"Indianapolis Motor Speedway","Location":{"lat":"39.795","long":"-86.2347","locality":"Indianapolis","country":"USA"}},"date":"1952-05-30"},{"season":"1952","round":"3","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_Belgian_Grand_Prix","raceName":"Belgian Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"spa","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Circuit_de_Spa-Francorchamps","circuitName":"Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps","Location":{"lat":"50.4372","long":"5.97139","locality":"Spa","country":"Belgium"}},"date":"1952-06-22"},{"season":"1952","round":"4","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_French_Grand_Prix","raceName":"French Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"essarts","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Rouen-Les-Essarts","circuitName":"Rouen-Les-Essarts","Location":{"lat":"49.3306","long":"1.00458","locality":"Rouen","country":"France"}},"date":"1952-07-06"},{"season":"1952","round":"5","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_British_Grand_Prix","raceName":"British Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"silverstone","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Silverstone_Circuit","circuitName":"Silverstone Circuit","Location":{"lat":"52.0786","long":"-1.01694","locality":"Silverstone","country":"UK"}},"date":"1952-07-19"},{"season":"1952","round":"6","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_German_Grand_Prix","raceName":"German Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"nurburgring","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/N%C3%BCrburgring","circuitName":"Nürburgring","Location":{"lat":"50.3356","long":"6.9475","locality":"Nürburg","country":"Germany"}},"date":"1952-08-03"},{"season":"1952","round":"7","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_Dutch_Grand_Prix","raceName":"Dutch Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"zandvoort","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Circuit_Zandvoort","circuitName":"Circuit Park Zandvoort","Location":{"lat":"52.3888","long":"4.54092","locality":"Zandvoort","country":"Netherlands"}},"date":"1952-08-17"},{"season":"1952","round":"8","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/1952_Italian_Grand_Prix","raceName":"Italian Grand Prix","Circuit":{"circuitId":"monza","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Autodromo_Nazionale_Monza","circuitName":"Autodromo Nazionale di Monza","Location":{"lat":"45.6156","long":"9.28111","locality":"Monza","country":"Italy"}},"date":"1952-09-07"}]}}}
```

and I deserialize this via this code:

```
var  jF1Season = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(strJSON);
```

The class structure is:

```
public class Root
    {
        public List<clsMRData> MRData { get; set; }
    }
    public class clsMRData
    {
        public string xmlns { get; set; }
        public string series { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string limit { get; set; }
        public string offset { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }
        public List<clsRaceTable> RaceTable { get; set; }
    }

    public class clsRaceTable
    {
        public string season { get; set; }
        public List<clsRace> Races { get; set; }
    }

    public class clsRace
    {
        public string season { get; set; }
        public string round { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string raceName { get; set; }
        public List<clsCircuit> Circuit { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
    }

    public class clsCircuit
    {
        public string circuitId { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string circuitName { get; set; }
        public List<clsLocation> Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class clsLocation
    {
        public string lat { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Root.MRData.RaceTable.Races.Circuit.Location.long")]
        public string lon { get; set; }
        public string locality { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
```

I guess the error is relating to how I have set this structure up, but cannot see why, so any help in solving this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Please review this highly active post which relates to your issue [Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several bugs in your code.Replace   List<clsRaceTable> ,  List<clsCircuit> , List<clsLocation>  with clsRaceTable,clsCircuit and clsLocation. Your classes should be

```
public class Root
{
    public clsMRData MRData { get; set; }
}
public class clsMRData
{
    public string xmlns { get; set; }
    public string series { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string limit { get; set; }
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public clsRaceTable RaceTable { get; set; }
}

public class clsRaceTable
{
    public string season { get; set; }
    public List<clsRace> Races { get; set; }
}

public class clsRace
{
    public string season { get; set; }
    public string round { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string raceName { get; set; }
    public clsCircuit Circuit { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class clsCircuit
{
    public string circuitId { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string circuitName { get; set; }
    public clsLocation Location { get; set; }
}

public class clsLocation
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "long")]
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}
```