# How to deserialize firebase fetch

Tags: c#, json, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im not quite sure how to go about deserializing the list i'm retrieving from my firebase database.

The fetch:

```
 var x = (await firebase
                .Child(ChildName)
                .OnceAsync<Userlogin>()).Select(item =>
                new Userlogin
                {
                    user_login = item.Object.user_login,
                    passwords = item.Object.passwords
                }).ToList();
```

The error im getting:

```
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

The Error is rather Self explanatory Im just not sure how to approach it, using the current method as its already going to a list so im just not sure

I tried something like :

```
  public async Task<List<Userlogin>> GetAllUser()
        {
            try
            {
                var x =  (await firebase
                .Child(ChildName)
                .OnceAsync<Userlogin>()).Select(item =>
                new Userlogin
                {
                    user_login = item.Object.user_login,
                    passwords = item.Object.passwords
                }).ToString();

                List<Userlogin> datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Userlogin>>(x);
             
              
                return datalist;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Crashes.TrackError(e);

                return null;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, please make sure the ChildName in the `Child(ChildName)` is the table name in the database.

And then, you can check [this case](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/issues/21) which has the same error and the problem is the structure of the data.

In addition, you can try the following code if you use `(item => new Userlogin{ }).ToString();`

```
datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Userlogin>>(content).Values.ToList()
```