# JsonSerializationException Cannot deserilaze the current Json Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to take the data from the web api service of the Gutenberg project and make a site in an mvc structure. But I encountered an error while pulling the data. I need help.
Web API: https://gutendex.com/

`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksFromApi()
        {
            var books = new List<BookModel>();

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://gutendex.com/books"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BookModel>>(apiResponse);
                }
            }
            return View(books);
        }
```

`

```
public class BookModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string[] Subjects { get; set; }
        public string[] Authors { get; set; }
        public string[] Translators { get; set; }
        public string[] Bookshelves { get; set; }
        public string[] Languages { get; set; }
        public bool Copyright { get; set; }
        public string Media_Type { get; set; }
        public string Formats { get; set; }
        public int Download_Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cftPu.png)

I wanted to use the json data received using the Newtonsoft package on my site, but I am getting an error in the conversion.

Comment: What data is in the response?

Comment: Duplicate [Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ).  Your model doesnt match the json

Comment: The api returns an object and you are trying to deserialize into an array. Go _look_ at the content returned by the API...it doesn't match what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

if you need just a collection of books you can extract it using Parse and after this to deserialize to a list. Fix your  BookModel class too

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

List<BookModel> results =JObject.Parse(json)["results"].ToObject<List<BookModel>>();


public class BookModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Subjects { get; set; }
    public object[] Authors { get; set; }
    public string[] Translators { get; set; }
    public string[] Bookshelves { get; set; }
    public string[] Languages { get; set; }
    public bool Copyright { get; set; }
    public string Media_Type { get; set; }
    public object Formats { get; set; }
    public int Download_Count { get; set; }
}
```

And I recommend to create custom classes instead of object for Authors and Formats properties