# ASP.NET API Call Exception: Cannot deserialize JSON Array. Requires JSON Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, blazor

I want to call an POST API Call and get some data. i use the swagger to do the call.
The Problem is i got an Exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

This is on the razor page:

```
using var client = await httpClientHelper.GetHttpClientWithAccessToken();
var result = await client.PostJsonAsync<JobDetail>($"{_serviceClientOptions.Value.BetriebstoolServiceAddress}/api/AbaReport?scope={scope}&mandant={mandant}&reportname={reportname}", body);
```

Here you have the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.User)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(JobDetail), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[SwaggerOperation("StartReport")]
public async Task<JobDetail> StartReport(int scope, int mandant, string reportname, string body)
{
   var result = await _abaReportService.StartReport(scope, mandant, reportname, body);
   return result;
}
```

Now the Service

```
public async Task<JobDetail> StartReport(int scope, int mandant, string reportname, string body)
        {
            var getscope = await _abacusBetriebstoolDatastoreService.GetServerAccessByScopeIdAsync(scope);
            var abacusClient = await _clientFactory.CreateClient<AbacusApiClient>(getscope.ServerDNS, getscope.UserID, getscope.Passwort);
            var result = await abacusClient.GetReportAsync(mandant, reportname, body);
            return result;
        }
```

At a point in the generated Code from Swagger, it tries to deserialize to json

```
using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                    {
                        var serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings);
                        var typedBody = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader); `<-- here ist the exception`
                        return new ObjectResponseResult<T>(typedBody, string.Empty);
                    }
```

Then i get the Exception!

And i see the point because when i try to call the api with Postman it looks like this:
[image]

The "result" is an array but it should be an object like in the example in swagger:
[image]

The response 'JobDetail' looks like this.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.3.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class JobDetail 
    {
        /// <summary>The id of the user that last logged in or an empty string, if no-one logged in</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Guid? Id { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("state", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
        public JobDetailState? State { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("message", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("finishedAt", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.DateTimeOffset? FinishedAt { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("result", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public TypedMap Result { get; set; }


    }
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.3.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class TypedMap 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("empty", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? Empty { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("size", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int? Size { get; set; }
    
    
    }
```

Why is the response an array? It should be a JSON object like in the swagger example.

I hope you can help me. Thank you :)

I searched a lot and found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ) or [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/704756/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array.html). But in my Problem i think the problem is in the generated code. i don't know

Comment: Wait a minute. You call an external api, and you don't like the result returned from there?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I call an api from a internal server in the companie, but i didn't get why the response is different than the response in the swagger file. I mean the code is generated by the swagger.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` property in the swagger is not correct. Swagger says is should be an object, while the response has it as an array. You should change the type of `public TypedMap Result { get; set; }` to a List. (but a list of which items?)

Comment: i cant change the code, because other API calls use this code and if i change it the other calls doesnt work anymore. but why is the result an empty array? i didn't get it

Comment: @saschafehr the API returns `"result": []` in the response as can be seen on your screenshot from postman

Comment: so the swagger schema that is generated on the api server is incorrect. You should contact the person responsible for it