# Json string to object C# syntax

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am new to .net and I am trying to convert JSON string to object. I have written following code but it gives me syntax errors:

```
JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
T obj = JSS.Deserialize<T>(String);
```

It doesn't recognize `T` in the code. Please help.

I dont want to create any custom class.
Can I get JSON from json string which I can use to find values of given keys

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979434/deserializing-json-array-into-strongly-type-net-object

Comment: Don't you need a class to deserialize, rather than a type e.g. `String`?

Comment: @gliese581g: 'Can I get JSON from json string which I can use to find values of given keys' - You mean like a `Dictionary<string, object>`? No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify `T` in anywhere.This code should be inside of a generic class or method where `T` is specified as generic type parameter.

Comment: In python, we can get json(dictionary) from json string. Can I get JSON from json string which I can use to find values of given keys.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code literally:

```
JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
T obj = JSS.Deserialize<T>(String);
```

`String` is a type, not an object. You need to pass in the variable you want to deserialize:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
}

// Then somewhere else

string json = @"{ ""Id"": 10, ""Name"": ""Jeremy Vines"" }";

JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Person obj = JSS.Deserialize<Person>(json);

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", obj.Id, obj.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing T with the object type that you are expecting to get. Or even object, if you don't know.