# Consuming JSON content using LINQ/C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm trying to process a number of files and move their data into a SharePoint List. I'm completely comfortable with the SharePoint component of my request but I'm struggling to wrap my head around taking JSON and performing C# statements against it.

The JSON I'm working with is in the following format:

```
{
  "details": {
    "persona": "jdfh sjahfj ashd",
    "firstName": "difdfsdfh",
    "surname": "safasfjhgfasdf",
    "email": "dfashfjsahf@dfjhdfjhsd.com",
    "phone": "3256545 421",
    "organisation": "dsfhjafd gas gdf",
    "department": "hsagfhsdgahjf",
    "address": {
      "street": "11/338 shjafg ash fg",
      "suburb": "gsagfghasf",
      "postcode": "4006"
    },
    "questions": {
      "iAmA": "fhsahjfsajhd df as",
      "iWorkAtA": "",
      "iAmSeekingFor": "ahshfjgsfggdh",
      "iAmAMemberOf": "dafjksfhdh",
      "furtherInfoOptIn": true,
      "newsletterOptIn": false,
      "privacyCollection": true
    }
  },
  "orders": [
    {
      "name": "Business Cards",
      "quantity": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "QUITLINE",
      "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979434/deserializing-json-array-into-strongly-typed-net-object) StackExchange request I've tried creating a class to deserialize my content into using the following:

```
var des = (ResourceOrdersJSONEntity)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sampleJSON, typeof(ResourceOrdersJSONEntity));
```

This isn't working for me and I suspect I'm looking down the completely wrong path. What do I need to be learning about in order to take the JSON and wrap linq statements around it for processing into SharePoint?

The error I'm receiving is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

I don't quite understand what it's indicating to me and I'm sure it's my class structure that's the problem, but I need a bit of guidance on how to fix it.

Here are the classes I've created for deserialization:

**Main Entity**
    public class ResourceOrdersJSONEntity
    {
        public List Details { get; set; }
        public List Orders { get; set; } 
    }

**Details**

```
public class ResourceOrdersDetailsEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the persona.
    /// </summary>
    public string Persona { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the first name.
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the surname.
    /// </summary>
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the email.
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phone.
    /// </summary>
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the organisation.
    /// </summary>
    public string Organisation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the department.
    /// </summary>
    public string Department { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the address.
    /// </summary>
    public ResourceOrdersAddressEntity Address { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the questions.
    /// </summary>
    public ResourceOrdersQuestionsEntity Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**Address Entity**

```
   public class ResourceOrdersAddressEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the street.
        /// </summary>
        public string Street { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the suburb.
        /// </summary>
        public string Suburb { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the postcode.
        /// </summary>
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
    }
```

**Questions Entity**

```
public class ResourceOrdersQuestionsEntity
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the i ama.
/// </summary>
public string IAma { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the i work at a.
/// </summary>
public string IWorkAtA { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the i am seeking for.
/// </summary>
public string IAmSeekingFor { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the i am a member for.
/// </summary>
public string IAmAMemberFor { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the further info opt in.
/// </summary>
public string FurtherInfoOptIn { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the news letter opt in.
/// </summary>
public string NewsLetterOptIn { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the privacy collection.
/// </summary>
public string PrivacyCollection { get; set; }
}
```

**Orders Entity**

```
public class ResourceOrdersQuantityEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the quantity.
    /// </summary>
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this var contactPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Obj>>(sampleJSON);

Comment: Looks like you are on the right path. Can you paste in the code for class `ResourceOrdersJSONEntity`? Also, when you say its not working, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Light I've just updated the code with that and still having issues. I suspect my classes are the problem (now added to question)?

Comment: @MikeHixson Added to question! Sorry was sitting in notepad and I forgot to bring it over after removing company data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get your code to work simply by changing `ResourceOrdersJSONEntity` to:

```
public class ResourceOrdersJSONEntity
{
    public ResourceOrdersDetailsEntity Details { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceOrdersQuantityEntity> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! You're on the money, thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceOrdersJSONEntity>(sampleJson)` method. It casts the JSON to the specified class.

As mentioned below. You'll have to change the **Main entity** to this

```
public class ResourceOrdersJSONEntity
{
    public ResourceOrdersDetailsEntity Details { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceOrdersQuantityEntity> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

In JSON objects are enclosed in curly brackets `{}` and arrays (which is the only kind of list/array/collection type in JSON) are enclosed in square brackets `[]`. JSON objects need to be converted to C# objects and JSON arrays need to be converted to a C# list/array/collection. This is why JSON.net is giving you an error when you are trying to convert the `"details"` object to a `List`

Comment: I've since made this change but still receiving an error - added classes and exception to the question since it looks to be like I'm on the right track but making errors somewhere in the construction of my classes

Answer (score 0):

Your ResourceOrdersJSONEntity class should be like this:

```
public class ResourceOrdersJSONEntity 
{ 
   public List Details { get; set; } 
   public List<ResourceOrdersQuantityEntity> Orders { get; set; } 
}
```