# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

**here the ex**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CCSN.Models.Patient]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '0', line 1, position 5.
```

**in this line to get patient**

`return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json);`

```
  public static async Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(string url)
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json);
        }
```

is the error from not converting?

and how can i convert to object or json

**this is the service to get Patient**

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> GetUserPatients()
        {
            var url = await firebaseClient
                     .Child($"Specalists/406707265/Patients").BuildUrlAsync();
 
            var result = await Helper.Get<List<Patient>>(url);
            return result ;
            
        }
```

**Changed the Get type, to try to match the json**

```cs
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> GetUserPatients()
        {
            var url = await firebaseClient
                     .Child($"Specalists/406707265/Patients").BuildUrlAsync();
            var patientsDict = await Helper.Get<Dictionary<string, Patient>>(url);
            var result = patientsDict.Values.ToList();
            return result ;
            
        }
```

Comment: Need more info about the crash. Look in VS Output pane - does it say what exception occurred? Maybe a stack trace? Also, put a breakpoint at start of method that crashes, and step through it - which line causes the exception/crash?

Comment: there is no output in VS

Comment: at first,the application is open,but when i add a Patient to firebase ,it work but the application then stopped and crach ,this the problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment will, I Turn on all"Common Language Runtime Exceptions", what do you mean by "popup"?

Comment: I run the code again, but nothing happens and the application stopped (crash) :(

Comment: If the application crashes, then there should be information about the crash in VS **Output/Show output from Debug** pane. You need that information, so you can add it to question. Until you have that, its impossible to help you. **You are running Debug build, right?**

Comment: yes, please check the edit

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like somewhere you have ONE Patient, but a LIST OF PATIENTS is expected. Its somewhere that involves JSON - either when writing to Firebase, or when reading back from Firebase. Perhaps `PatientServices Addpat`. Breakpoint start of that, and step through each line until it crashes. Then compare the code to what's in firebase - is something expecting a list of patients?

Comment: which **specific line** causes the exception?

Comment: `await patientService.Addpat(pat);` 
from debug

Comment: that is **your code**.  Which line in that method causes the exception?

Comment: the exception appear at the first when i run the code

Comment: So you are saying that the first line of `Addpat` causes the exception?  There are three distinct operations on that line - `new Patient(patient)`, `Child` and `PostAsync`.  Now you need to figure out which one causes the exception.  Try breaking up each operation into its own line.  And what is the purpose of  `new Patient(patient)`?   Why are you creating another instance of `Patient` when you already have one?

Comment: i found the specific line,please check the edits:(

Comment: Pls check  this FYR 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979434/deserializing-json-array-into-strongly-typed-net-object & 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ

Answer (score 1):

The back and forth in comments has gotten unwieldy. Here is a community wiki showing the status of resolving this.

Exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CCSN.Models.Patient]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '0', line 1, position 5.
```

NOTE: Exception says is trying to deserialize into

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CCSN.Models.Patient]'

In c# that would be a `List<Patient>`.

Statement in PatientServices.Addpat in which exception is believed to occur:

```cs
        var x = await firebaseClient
                .Child($"Specalists/406707265/Patients")
                .PostAsync(new Patient(patient));
```

Those statements must lead to this - the lower-level line in which exception occurs:

```cs
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json);
```

---

1. json (skipping most of it):

```json
{
  "0":{
   "Appointments":[
    {"AppointmentDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00+03:00"
    }
   ],
   "ID": "0",
   "PatientName": "Ghaidaa"
  },

 "-N-tZ6hbyPpWOWeoo9o4": {
   "ID": "45455184",
   "PatientName": "sgagaga"
  }
}
```

2. TEntity:

Based on the error message, TEntity is presumably `List<Patient>`.

---

The problem is that the `json` (shown above) isn't in the expected format. It is a `dynamic object` with keys `"0"`, `"1"`, `"-N-tZ6hbyPpWOWeoo9o4"`.

The calling code is expecting a json `array`, which would look like this:

```json
[ {
   "Appointments":[
    {"AppointmentDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00+03:00"
    }
   ],
   "ID": "0",
   "PatientName": "Ghaidaa"
  },

  {
   "ID": "45455184",
   "PatientName": "sgagaga"
  }
]
```

The difference is easiest to see by examining the beginning and end of the json.

---

**One way to fix is to deserialize to a `Dictionary`.** Then extract the values of the Dictionary into a list.

Find code that looks something like the line below. Replace:

```cs
    var patients = await Helper.Get<List<Patient>>(url);
```

With:

```cs
    var patientsDict = await Helper.Get<Dictionary<string, Patient>>(url);
    var patients = patientsDict.Values;
```

Or depending on how you use it, might change the last line to:

```cs
    var patients = patientsDict.Values.ToList();
```

---

**An ALTERNATIVE way to fix** is to change the server side, so that it sends an `array of Patients` instead of a `dynamic object`.

--- Making that change is beyond the scope of this answer ---

Comment: please check the question again, I post the photos

Comment: sorry, I'm new to Xamarin and I do not know all this information, I try to learn it :(

Comment: ,Please check the edits

Comment: **this is the git mothed**

```
      public static async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> GetUserPatients()
        {
            var url = await firebaseClient
                     .Child($"Specalists/406707265/Patients").BuildUrlAsync();

            var result = await Helper.Get<List<Patient>>(url);
            return result ;
            
        }
```

Comment: I try your soluation but it give the same ex on

``` return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json);```

Comment: done,please check

Comment: I edit it ,same like what you say

Comment: when I put your solution, the application did not open :(

Comment: it gives me the same expectation

Comment: Does the exception still say `... into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[CCSN.Models.Patient]' ...`, or does it now give a different type after "into type"?  If different, what type does it say now?

Comment: yes, the same as the question

Comment: Are you sure it is **exactly** the same message? If it says `... into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[CCSN.Models.Patient]'`, then it must be code somewhere else that is using `json`. The code I suggested, if it gave that error, would say `... into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'1[String, CCSN.Models.Patent] ...`. Do you have any other places that refer to `json` and `List<Patient>`?

Comment: ```...'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,CCSN.Models.Patient]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.```

Comment: Ok, Dictionary did not help. Go back to your original code that used `Get<List<Patient>>`. I recommend getting some firebase example to work. Then gradually change the example until it does what you need. Google `firebase database xamarin work with list`. Perhaps https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/.